# Can you give an inductive definition to define the length of a list L?

Tags: induction

Having trouble understanding what it means to define something inductively in the following context.

> Can you give an inductive to define the length of a list L?
>
> a. The total number of items in L is the length of L
>
> b. Basis: the length of an empty list is 0
>   Induction: the length of a list is 2*(length of half the list)
>
> c. Basis: the length of an empty list is 0
>   Induction: the length of a list is (length of head(list))+(length of tail(list))
>
> **d. Basis: the length of an empty list is 0
>   Induction: the length of a list is 1+(length of tail(list))**

The answer is (d). Why might this be?

And also for this similar question:

> Can you give an inductive definition to define what it means for an element X to
>   be a member of a list L?
>
> a. X is a member of a list L if and only if X belongs to the list L.
>
> **b. X is a member of a list L if either X is the head of the list or X is a member of the tail of L.**
>
> c. X is a member of a list L if we can find an element Y in L and X=Y.
>
> d. X is a member of a list L if we can find an element Y in the tail of L

The answer is (b).

Thank you.

Comment: A multiple choice question beginning with "can you..." should have two possible answers: yes and no.

Answer (score 1):

In an inductive definition what you have to do is to find a base case and the inductive step.

In your case, suppose to have a list $L$ and let head be the first element and tail the rest of the list.

For example, if $L=[1,2,3,4,5]$:

- head = $1$
- tail = $[2,3,4,5]$

In order to understand the meaning you could consider writing a recursive function to compute the length of the list.

According to the answer

- Basis: the length of an empty list is *0*
- Induction: the length of a list is *1+(length of tail(list))*

This corresponds to the recursive function

```
function len(list L)
   if L is empty
        return 0
   else return 1 + len(tail(L))
```

Same for the second question:

```
function member(elem x, list L)
   if L is empty
       return false
   if head == x 
       return true
   else return member(x, tail(L))
```

and this corresponds to say: X is a member of a list L if either

- X is the head of the list or
- X is a member of the tail of L.

Comment: This definition is not inductive but recursive.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13225/inductive-vs-recursive-definition